# How to stop product number 10 to push down the product number 9 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This question and its title might come across as a vague question and I am sorry if it does but I have no other way of asking it as I am confused myself.

okay here it goes:

I am creating a website where the site owner can post products with their images on the homepage! This bit works fine.

The homepage will only show a maximum of 10 products. This bit works as well.

The products get stored in the database by numbers. for example: the first item/product is saved as product number 1 and 1 is its ID and product number 2 is 2 and 3 is 3 and so on.
this bit also works fine as I want it to work.

here is the issue:

Lets say I have added 10 products to the homepage which is the Max it can show on teh homepage. Products 1 to 10.

When I add a new product (product number 11 ), this newly added product will remove the oldest product added which is product number 1.

I do not want this to happen. I need for the products/items to stay in a queue sort of way and get stored in the database like other products UNTIL i delete/remove one of the old ones manually and it will automatically will be replaced.

This is the code that I am using for adding the products into the database:

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
    $retail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['retail']);
    $clicks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clicks']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']);
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="index.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, link, retail, clicks, price, details, category, subcategory, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$link','$retail','$clicks','$price','$details','$category','$subcategory',now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    header("location: index.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

any help would be greately helpful. even if its putting me in a right direction.

Thanks

Comment: so just select the 10 most recent products... `select ... order by id DESC limit 10`.

Comment: Posting your DB table schema might help.

Comment: What about the code of the homepage which you want to change products displaying on?

Comment: Marc B - his problem is the oldest record is being dumped off the homepage, and he doesn't want that. Therefore, DESC with LIMIT is what is currently happening.

Comment: @Trent, Yes, you are absolutely correct. that is the issue! any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB Schema is unnecessary to us. This is an ordering issue. You'll probably find, on your SQL query that fetches the items for the homepage, something like "ORDER BY id DESC" or a date. You need to order your items by id ASC (which is default behaviour for SQL, therefore simply "ORDER BY id" would be sufficient.

To repeat - your SQL is specifically ordering the records DESC on either a date or ID.

Comment: No worries mate. I highly suggest you head over to w3schools and learn SQL - most database engines are the same for these ANSI standard commands.